# Angle DIV in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, rotation

I'm stumped by IE!  Is it possible to angle a DIV in IE.  I'm currently using the following in all the other browsers:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [cssSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/). It's doing rotations and more. [Example.](http://www.useragentman.com/tests/cssSandpaper/rotateTest.html)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm trying it with my input fields and textarea's... so far no bueno.

Erik

Answer (score 0):

there's a few ways to create CSS shapes, crossbrowser, apparently.

Tantek Celic did it here: http://www.tantek.com/CSS/Examples/polygons.html

Otherwise, google pure CSS shapes :)

First result for me:
http://www.russellheimlich.com/blog/pure-css-shapes-triangles-delicious-logo-and-hearts/

Comment: I think I wrote my question wrong.  If you look at my contact form: www.erikrp.com/contact.htm in Safari, Opera, and Firefox, you will find the fields (inside DIV's) are angled.  How do I achieve this in IE?